# Angular2 dynamic components and TP jQuery library

Tags: jquery, angularjs, dynamic, components

I'm porting my previous app from Angular1 to Angular2.

It uses a tricky mechanism - dynamically created components should be inserted in specific DOM Elements which are managed (created/destroyed) by a layout plugin based on jQuery.

I made the plugin to init properly in the new environment but is it possible to make Angular know about the dynamically created HTMLElments?

I've read many things about dynamic components, and there is no problem with instantiating one - but I can't find an answer how can I inject them in custom Elements.

In angular1 i just used `$compile` and appended the result. How should i do it in ng2? Is there a way to transform those host elements to `ViewContainerRef`s somehow?

Answer (score 0):

```
<p>My string msg {{name}}</p>
```

or

innerthml set value into tag in example `<span>some text</span>`

```
title: any = 'some text';

<span [innerHTML]="title"></span>
```